# Is $\frac{nx}{n^{2}x^{2}+1}$ Cauchy in uniform norm (I guess it is not Cauchy but am not sure about my proof)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, cauchy-sequences

The sequence $f_{n}(x)=\frac{nx}{n^{2}x^{2}+1}$, for $x\in[0,1]$, pointwise converges function $f(x)=0$.

Is $\left\{f_{n}(x)\right\}$ Cauchy with the norm $||\cdots||_{\infty}$?

Comment: Do you mean $n^2x^2$ in the denominator?

Comment: Yes I will correct it. Sorry for that.

Comment: Note that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}=1/2$

Comment: @Dr.MV I tried to find the maximal value of $\frac{nx}{n^{2}x^{2}+1}-\frac{mx}{m^{2}x^{2}+1}$ by taking its derivative with respect to x and solve the equation, but it seems very complicated.

Comment: Let $\epsilon=\frac16$.  Next, for all $N$ take $n=2m>N$ and take $x=1/n$.  Then, we have $$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|=\left|\frac{1}{1+1}-\frac{1/2}{1+(1/2)^2}\right|=\frac16=\epsilon$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\displaystyle \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in [0,1]} f_n(x)\ge f_n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=1/2\not \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Could you please check my answer and leave a comment?

Comment: Actually, the supremum is $1/2$ at $x=1/n$.  There is a strict equality and no need for the inequality.

Comment: Yes. But to find the supremum we have to show upto 2nd order derivative.